# Sum of times value in one column appears in another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of the customers check out funnel through an app and a table of total sales. I want to find the number of sales that can be attributed to the app. I think the easiest way to do this is to concatenate the name and barcode in both of these tables. Then I can see if the values column, NameVIN, for the sales table appear in NameVIN for the checkout funnel table.

For obvious reasons I will not be sharing data for this question.

```
NameVIN = 
if(
    ConsumerFunnelTime[CustomerFirstName] <> BLANK() && ConsumerFunnelTime[CustomerLastName] <> BLANK(), ConsumerFunnelTime[CustomerFirstName] & ConsumerFunnelTime[CustomerLastName] & ConsumerFunnelTime[VIN],BLANK())
```

```
NameVIN = 
if(
    'Sales'[c_Customer1FirstName] <> BLANK() && 'Sales'[c_Customer1LastName] <> BLANK(), 'Sales'[c_Customer1FirstName] || 'Sales'[c_Customer1LastName] & 'Sales'[v_VIN],BLANK())
```

This is what I tried to see of there is a matching value for NameVIN in both Sales and Consumer Funnel

```
VAR x = VALUES(ConsumerFunnelTime[NameVIN])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(ConsumerFunnelTime),
    ALL(),
    TREATAS( x, 'Sales'[NameVIN])
) + 0
```

I also tried this, but it is giving me an error for the syntax of CALCULATE.

```
DarwinSales = 
VAR UsersNameVIN = ConsumerFunnelTime[NameVIN]
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Sales'[NameVIN]),
    'Sales'[NameVIN] = UsersNameVIN
)
```

Comment: For obvious reasons you shouldn't bother StackOverflow with your business problems and business data but provide a minimal, reproducible example that is potentially relevant for other users too.

Comment: @Peter I believe looking to see if a value is present in another column is widely applicable

Answer (score 0):

```
WasSale = 
LOOKUPVALUE('Sales'[NameVIN], 'Sales'[NameVIN], ConsumerFunnelTime[NameVIN])
```

```
DarwinSales = 
DISTINCTCOUNT(ConsumerFunnelTime[WasSale])
```